# Powershell Check Scheduled Task Status

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I've got a PS1 script that is automatically run by Windows Task Scheduler and checks the status of a different scheduled task on the same machine.

```
If ((Get-ScheduledTask  -CimSession Sever1 -TaskName Task1).State -eq 'Disabled')
    {
    Do Something
        }
    Exit
    }
ElseIf ((Get-ScheduledTask  -CimSession Sever1-TaskName Task1).State -eq 'Ready')
    {
    Exit
    }
```

When I run this manually through a Powershell ISE window this works fine, however when I run this script from Windows Task Scheduler it will not return the state of the other task, it's just blank. Why does this not work when running it as a scheduled task? Is there a different command or parameter that I need to use?

Comment: In an interactive session (console host or ISE) screen response is displayed by design. Stuff from the Task Scheduler is not, by design, unless your code is starting PowerShell in an interactive session and set to wait so you can see it. True background automation tasks, are designed to be invisible to the user(s).